# which hive table gives better performance?

Tags: hadoop, hive

i'm beginner to hadoop.

internal table: the table is stored in hive warehouse and if it is dropped, both the metadata and data is deleted.
external table: the table is stored in hdfs and if it is dropped, only the metadata is deleted.
now, which table gives better performance while querying?please give reason.

also, it is highly appreciable if you could give some more difference for this tables in real time.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance difference at all between internal table and external table. The only difference is just like what you mentioned - one thing to note is hive warehouse is also in HDFS (with different path)

Comment: ok thank you....could you please tell me some more difference between these tables in real time scenarios.

Comment: External tables are recommended in most scenarios - since the data files are going into each user's workspace instead of a shared hive warehouse, the cluster admins will gain the benefits such as easier management on ACLs and HDFS quotas if the cluster is shared by different users.